# UnitTesting single-page AngularJS application with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a single page AngularJS application that has about 3-4 different views.

How can I write another view for Jasmine unit tests so that the Jasmine UI doesn't show up on every single view?

Comment: Usually tested views shouldn't interfere with Jasmine UI because views are supposed to be compiled in detached nodes. And usually there shouldn't be Jasmine UI at all if you run tests with Karma (and you probably should do that). There's not enough data on test setup.

Comment: Running a Golang back-end, and don't want to set up Karma/Node just for the UnitTests.

Comment: Then consider providing current code that you have for your tests because it isn't clear enough what's going on there.

Comment: I haven't written a single test yet. I just included the jasmine HTML/JS/CSS files in my `index.html` file, and the Jasmine UI popped up right there.

Comment: It's either one or another. Use Karma if you need something more than basic Jasmine HTML reporter. Usually you need Node for NPM and tools any way.

Comment: For this project, I am not using Node whatsoever. Not using NPM, nothing. Is there anyway to use the Jasmine HTML reporter in a way that there's a specific view setup in Angular (`app_url/#/tests`) or something similar where this reporter shows up rather than on every single page?

Comment: This has more to do with testing methodology rather than with reporter. Entire views shouldn't be tested in unit tests, individual units should. The thing you're trying to do is likely e2e test, and e2e are done with Protractor (and you'll need Node for it).

Comment: No, I don't want to do e2e tests. I want unit tests for the controller functions. I just want there to be one page where I can go see the results of all the unit tests.

Comment: Then it's not clear what you're trying to do. What is app_url/#/tests? There should be only 1 page and it is supposed to contain Jasmine UI. No other pages.

Comment: I have an app with 4 existing pages. I want to add a 5th page which will contain the Jasmine UI that will show the test results for all the other page controllers. Does that make sense?

Comment: I would say that the page with Jasmine tests should be a separate page that has nothing to do with regular app.

Comment: Right, that's what I want to do. I want to have a separate page for Jasmine tests. Those tests would be testing the rest of the app.

Comment: What is the problem then? Only Jasmine UI should be available on this page, not application views.

Comment: When I include the Jasmine HTML/javascript code, I do it on index.html which is the base view for my app. All other views are child views. As a result, the Jasmine HTML reporter shows up on every single page.

Comment: What were the reasons? I would suggest to not do this. It should be a separate HTML file that runs in isolation and doesn't depend on what happens on index.html.